# chrome extension to Send Message from popup to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, message-passing

I,am developing an extension in which i have to extract data from linkedin profile page when user press button on popup. I,am passing message from the popup.js page to contentscript and in response i will get data extracted from linkedin profile page by contentscript so that i can display it in popup.html. But I,am getting error when i inspected the popup.html. The error is:

```
Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. lastError:29
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://kdfgoafjicddfffdbfofdmckejemfije/popup.js:6:25
    at <error: illegal access>
    at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:356:21)
    at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:342:27)
    at Event.dispatch (event_bindings:362:17)
    at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect (miscellaneous_bindings:258:27)
```

**For reference, my manifest file is:**

```
{
    "name": "SoftwareGrid",
    "version": "0.5",
    "icons": { "16": "icons/16.png","48": "icons/48.png", "128": "icons/128.png" },
    "description": "Shows user cresidentials on Linkedin",
    "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "tabs",
        "http://www.linkedin.com/*"
    ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Show Profile",
        "default_icon": { "16": "icons/16.png","48": "icons/48.png", "128": "icons/128.png" },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js","background.js"]
    }, 

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://www.linkedin.com/*"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js", "script.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "icons/i1.png"
    ],

    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**My popup.js file:**

```
function sendClicks() {
    console.log("popup.js > sendClicks()");

    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
        });
    });

    console.log("avra' inviato?");
}

$(function() {
    console.log("popup.js > OMD Extension ready");
    $('#sendclicks').click(function(){
        sendClicks();
    });
});
```

**My contentscript file**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");

        if (request.greeting == "hello")
            sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

Plz help!

Comment: It works for me. Maybe you have done error on debug and you have changed your tab? If you are using `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, ...` this tab have to be open and active while you are debugging, otherwise listener on `script.js` isn't called.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i was stupid as there was an error in my content script

Comment: What was the error in your content script? Can you put the correct file as an answer?

Comment: This question is hanging in popular unanswered questions for [google-chrome-extension] tag. Since this question is, essentially, answered - please either post and accept an answer, or delete the question if you feel it's not worth keeping.

Answer (score 3):

You may have to add this in your manifest:

```
"permissions" : ["tabs"]
```